# How to invoke method from datacontrol programmatically?

Tags: java

I have created 2 projects in my application. One for "View" and other one for "Model". In model I have created a java class and then made it as a DataControl The methods implemented in java classes are displaying under datacontrol Now I have created a java class in view(Managed bean), from here how can i invoke the method defined in DataControl programmatically

I am not using pagedefinition files. Can anyone give me some sample examples or code to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using pagedefs? This is a very powerfull feature of ADF

Answer (score 1):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
BindingContext bindingContext = BindingContext.getCurrent();
DCDataControl dc  = bindingContext.findDataControl("AppModuleAMDataControl"); // Name of application module in datacontrolBinding.cpx
AppModuleAMImpl appM = (AppModuleAMImpl)dc.getDataProvider();
```

Read more: http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2012/11/get-object-of-applicationmodule-in-managed-bean-in-adf-techartifact.html#ixzz3oHhI8yqX